# cuSOLVER automatically parallelizes computation on many matrices?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cusolver

I have to make same computations (for example, get eigenvalues of `A1, A2, ...`) `on many(>10^15)` matrices, so I want use threads as many as possible. 
But I couldn't find cuBLAS or cuSOLVER codes stating number of threads. Does cuSOLVER automatically distribute resources and parallelize computations if I write code with for loop and cuSOLVER functions? 
Or is there any cuSOLVER or cuBLAS API that I can control the number of threads and parallelize functions?
......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does cuSOLVER automatically distribute resources and parallelize computations if I write code with for loop and cuSOLVER functions?

No.

> Or is there any cuSOLVER or cuBLAS API that I can control the number of threads and parallelize functions?

No.

But, if you care to read the CUSOLVER [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#csrqr_batch_examples), you will see that there is a batched sparse QR factorization routine. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) can be used to solve [eigenvalue problems](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallel-direct-solvers-with-cusolver-batched-qr/).

Comment: It's really hard to understand batched QR factorization. What does exactly 'batched' means? If I 'batch' M NxN matrices, GPU solves MNxMN matrices or NxN matrices parallel or just solve it one by one? And can I make custom 'batch' operations?

Comment: If you submit a batch of N matrices, it will compute the N  factorizations in the most efficient way which uses all the available GPU compute capacity. As for the rest, I don't know what that means. You asked about eigenvalues, and that is what my answer describes